# "Web Content" widget with datasets in PowerBI dashboard

Tags: powerbi

Can we populate the data in "Web Content" widget while creating PowerBI dashboard?
E.g. - I have my Power BI dashboard and currently I am adding a Web content widget to the dashboard.
Inserting HTML is an easy task but I wonder if i could insert some data from available datasets from the associated reports of that specific dashboard.
Would it be possbile? if yes, could some one provide me few pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lukasz, but found one turn around, just created .NET application with DB connected to the web pages.
All these webpages are then hosted as iframes into the "Web Content" widget.
By this I could get the DB records from my Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML widget does not support receiving data. If you'd like something that is data bound, you can use a custom visual.